# Can't connect Redux store to functional component (Screen)

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, react-props

I've set up a Redux store in my RN application. The store works fine, if I use store.getState() I can see all the data inside my store. However, if I try to retrieve it from connect, it doesn't work. I think it's due to the fact that I'm using a functional component and not a class.

**App.js** (also functional component)

```
return (
<Provider store={store}>
  <NavigationContainer>
    <Stack.Navigator >                   
          
          <Stack.Screen name="Home" 
            options={({ navigation, route }) => ({
              headerTitle: 'Hi, {nome}',
              headerRight:() => (
                <Pressable onPress={() => updateLogin(false)}>
                  <Text>
                    Log Out
                  </Text>
                </Pressable>
              ),
              headerBackVisible: false
            })} 
            component={HomeScreen} 
          />
          <Stack.Screen name="Calendar" component={CalendarScreen} />            
          <Stack.Screen name="SignUp" component={SignUpMainScreen} options={{headerShown:false}}/>
          <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} options={{headerShown:false}}/>
          <Stack.Screen name="SignUpEmail" component={SignUpEmailScreen} options={{headerShown:false}}/>           
       
    </Stack.Navigator>
  </NavigationContainer>
</Provider>
```

**Homescreen.js**

```
//Other imports 

import * as React from 'react';    
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import store from '../api/redux/store';
import {updateLogin} from '../api/redux/actions'


function HomeScreen({ navigation}) {   
    
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>  
            <Text>{this.props.user.name}</Text>
            
        </View>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({...})

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    name: state.user.name,
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(HomeScreen)
```

Comment: I suggest you use the `useSelector` hook instead, `connect` is rather meant for class components.

Answer (score 1):

I always recommend using hooks in functional components since its way easier to read and understand.

In this case it would be:

```
import {useSelector} from 'react-redux'

const name = useSelector(state => state.user.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I found the answer myself. You need to pass as props to the screen the props that you define inside `mapStateToProps()`.

In this case,

```
name: state.user.name
```

goes inside `HomeScreen({navigation, name})`.

you can find it [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/redux-integration/) even though the example was not super clear.